# Cookie-less form login to Symfony2 site

Tags: php, session, symfony, safari

I've got a symfony site that is designed to be used in an iframe on another site. For all browsers it works fine, except Safari, because Safari doesn't let an iframe set any cookies. Instead of logging in, I am returned to a blank login page with no errors.

The solution I've been trying is to set PHPSESSID as a hidden field on the form, and use that to keep track of the session instead of a cookie. The problem I have is that after logging in, formlogin seems to set a new session key and send a redirect. I can't get the right session key on this redirect.

I've tried to add the session key to the end of the redirected URL by adding the following to the end of the app.php (this is very unsymfonic, but I'm getting pretty desperate).

```
foreach(headers_list() as $header) {
    if (substr($header,0,9) == "location:") {
        if (strpos($header, '?')===FALSE && strpos($header, '#')===FALSE ) {
            header($header."?PHPSESSID=".session_id());
        }
    }
}
```

This adds a session key, but it seems to be adding the old session key, not the new one that has been created by the form login. As a result, when I try to login I get the message "Your session has timed-out, or you have disabled cookies.".

How can I get the right session_id? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you simply write an action that will return current session id by requesting it?

Answer (score 1):

What you get is simply additional security check to prevent malicious users to fake sessions. The same behavior will happen if you'll try to load the page with the login form, then remove all cookies, then try to authenticate.

The check is defined at [this line](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php#L129). The checking method is [self-explained](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L552) and pretty clear.

For your special task I'd say that this would be not preferred behavior, so you should override this class.

There is quite good documentation on [how to write custom authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) - that could be the start point for your inspiration ;)